# Using wood filler on garden furniture

Tags: repair, wood, furniture, epoxy, dry-rot

I want to repair some weather battered garden table, bench and chair set. It has had some in places, so I will be replacing the severely rotten sections, and scraping out the rot from the partially damaged pieces.

My intention, with the partially damaged sections it to use a [wood hardener](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-Wet-Rot-Wood-Hardener-500ml/p/600075) to firm up the remaining wood, and then fill the gaps with a [wood filler](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Ronseal-High-Performance-Wood-Filler-White-550g/p/117941).

Once the wood filler has dried, I will be painting the whole set to hide the filled pieces.

I have limited experience in this area, so I would like to know if there are any caveats or gotchas to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Miniwax Wood Hardener after removing rotted wood and have been pleased with the results. Also, when I do a repair like you're doing, I use an exterior grade epoxy. What you're considering should be fine. I also attach screws into the wood below the surface to better hold the epoxy in place.

Answer (score 0):

If the furniture is in the weather, not sheltered, the wood will expand and contract with seasonal changes and water saturation. The product you have in mind reminds me of bondo. which I have used for filler for large hole in non-structural items. In furniture, everything, for the most part, is structural.The wood filler will not move with the wood and will fall out. It will be best to repair with wood and an exterior rated glue. I would not hold my breath even if the furniture was sheltered. Uncontrolled humidity/moisture is what is the bad guy here.
On second thought, I have a little experience with epoxy wood filler, that will hold under extreme conditions. This is different than the two part system you depicted. Shipwrights use the product I refer to. It is messy and will not clean up easily. There may be a thick enough product to build up and hold like you like you want it to do though.

Comment: Is there a particular epoxy product I should be looking at?

Comment: This product states it is useful for exteriour use http://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-Super-Tough-Wood-Filler-550g/p/600073

Comment: Both appear the same polyester based products, same as bondo. here is a link to a product I have used before, http://www.westsystem.com/ss/  I hope it is available in your neck of the woods. If not there should be compatible products on your end that will do the same. It is pretty much resin and hardener for fiberglass mat.